# A question on CSS height

Tags: html, css, height

I have an CSS like

```
    DIV.header_links
    {
        float:right; font-family:"Trebuchet MS" arial; font-size:12px; margin-top:19px; margin-bottom:19px;
        width:100px; background-color:blue; text-align:center; 
    }
```

Now the tag `<DIV class = "header_links">` has a wrapper `DIV` around it which has height of `50px`

- Is it safe to assume that the inner DIV ie `DIV.header_links` will not overflow.
- Should `margin-top:19px, margin-bottom:19px and font-size:12px` give a sum of 50 px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe to assume that the inner DIV ie DIV.header_links will not overflow.

Yes, as long as it is `display: block;` (which it is by default)

> Should margin-top:19px, margin-bottom:19px and font-size:12px give a sum of 50 px?

Not necessarily. You can use the value of the `overflow` property for the header_link `div` to determine how it's contents appear. See: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp for more info.

**Edit:**

Here is a better article on the CSS `overflow` property: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/

Comment: No w3cschools only -> [link]www.w3fools.com

Comment: @Sourav, please feel free to suggest a better link for the CSS `overflow` property; not *all* of W3Schools is bad. Though I agree we should think twice before using/suggesting it.

Comment: The idea here was to put a text at middle of a DIV. Now, as font-size:12px does not add 12px in height, I need to find out someway to put the text in the middle. `display:table-cell` does not work in some browsers, and line-height solution does not look good for multiple lines. Is there any way to put a text at the middle of a DIV.

Comment: @Mayank, the only other way I can think of is to use `vertical-align: middle` but remember to use that **on** the element you want vertically aligned (except that it can used on table rows directly too).

Answer (score 1):

1) Is it safe to assume that the inner DIV ie DIV.header_links will not overflow.

I'm pretty sure it won't overflow unless you got a total height with margins of 51px or more.

2) Should margin-top:19px, margin-bottom:19px and font-size:12px give a sum of 50 px?

```
margin-top:19px
margin-bottom:19px
height:12px 
/*gives a sum of 50 px.*/
```

and

```
margin-top:19px
margin-bottom:19px
line-height: 12px 
/*gives a sum of 50 px.*/
```

font-size doesn't affect the height of any element. line-height or height does.

Answer (score 0):

> Should margin-top:19px, margin-bottom:19px and font-size:12px give a sum of 50 px?

Not in the case if there are more than one line.

> Is it safe to assume that the inner DIV ie DIV.header_links will not overflow.

Yes.